# When will be a post considered as a first post?

Tags: discussion, support, review

If the first post of a user got deleted, then that user posted another one.

Will it be considered as a first post?

ie, will it be shown on the first posts review queue?

I have another question on same title,

If a user posted a question and then posted his/her first answer post,

will it be queued in the first posts queue?

Comment: If the second post is **not** considered as a first post after the first post is deleted, it should be a feature request.

Comment: It is, see [Meta Crypto: Old question suddenly appears in the first posts queue](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/280/old-question-suddenly-appears-in-the-first-posts-queue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, if all the posts(questions and answers) got deleted,then the next post of that user will be considered as first post and will be shown in the review-queue.

If the user posted one or more questions and posted the first answer or vice versa, then it will not be a first post and not be shown on first post review queue.